# proxy_pass in nginx seems to be skipped and REACT axios POST call went to wrong address

Tags: reactjs, nginx, proxypass

I am new to nginx and have been looking for solutions but to no avail.  In nginx.conf file, I have something like:

```
server {
    location /core-api {
      proxy_pass http://backend.companyname.com/core-api;   
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

In REACT, I have the following code:

```
  register(...args) {
    return axios.post('/core-api/register', ...args)
  }
```

What I want to happen is to have axios POST call go to:

```
http://backend.companyname.com/core-api/register
```

What has been happening is POST request would land itself at:

```
http://www.companyname.com/core-api/register
```

and I would get 502 error.

Do you know what went wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: 502 means that your backend (http://backend.companyname.com/core-api) is not available on port 80. Can you access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

We have faced a similar problem, where the backend was running behind AWS beanstalk. The issue was that the backend will keep changing its IPs behind the DNS, which causes the issue for nginx.

I have seen this scenario in a few blogs and applied the below, see if that works for you.

```
server {
    location /core-api {
      set $backend 'backend.companyname.com';
      proxy_pass http://$x;   
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Additionally, if you have nginx+ you can move this to upstreams with resolver. It will be good if you can provide more information about your backends.